# Which are the morphisms for sets with semimetrics?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, category-theory

A semimetric is due to Wikipedia defined as a metric but without the triangle inequality. Intuitively it seems possible to define some kind of continuity for functions between such sets $f:A\to B$, a "small change" in input will result in only a "small change" of output:
$$\forall\epsilon>\!0\,\exists\delta>0: d(a,a')<\delta\implies d(f(a),f(a'))<\epsilon$$
but generally the triangle inequality is needed to show that the composition of two continuous functions is continuous.

So which are the morphisms in the category of sets with semimetrics?

Comment: ...are you sure the triangle inequality is needed to show that the composition of two functions verifying the property you wrote is continuous?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: your are right, I was sloppy.

Comment: By the way: Continuous mappings are arguably not the right kind of morphism between *plain* metric spaces, because they are a topological concept. E.g. homeomorphisms don't preserve completeness.

Comment: It is only the ordering of the distance-values that plays a role in composition (either of continuous maps or of the $1$-Lipshitz maps you've defined). For a fixed $\epsilon>0$ continuity of $B\xrightarrow{g}C$ at $f(a)\in B$ gives a $\delta'>0$ so that $d(f(a),f(a'))<\delta'\implies d(g(f(a)),g(f(a')))<\epsilon$, and for that $\delta'>0$ continuity of $A\xrightarrow{f}B$ at $a\in A$ gives a $\delta>0$ so that $d(a,a')<\delta\implies d(f(a),f(a'))<\delta'$. Altogether we have, $d(a,a')<\delta\implies d(f(a),f(a'))<\delta'\implies d(g(f(a)),g(f(a'))<\epsilon$.

Comment: @StefanPerko that's kind of backwards, at least from a categorical point of view since metric completeness is a universal property in terms of the "non-expansive maps" that Lehs defined. This means that being "non-expansive" is not an elementary categorical property of whatever larger class of morphisms you decide to have, but that's ok.

Comment: *Lehs actually defined uniformly continuous functions, not non-expansive ones.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov That's my point (unless I'm confused). Continuous maps are not the right concept, but $1$-Lipschitz maps (at least for metric spaces).

Comment: @StefanPerko I'm saying that your justification for considering 1-Lipschitz maps "the right concept" because completeness is expressible as a universal property in terms of 1-Lipschitz maps is flimsy: you only care about completeness in the first place because of analytic considerations, and analytic consideration deems continuous maps and uniformly continuous maps to be just as good if not more important concepts. I think it's a great shame that (at least as far as I know) the notion of a "continuous enriched functor" has not been explored.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov Arguably, the category of "metric spaces" with continuous maps is simply the full subcategory of $\mathsf{Top}$ of metrizable topological spaces and I think similar things can be said about uniform maps. Cauchy completeness is an important concept in enriched category theory (e.g. see Morita equivalence of algebraic theories) so it seems kind of weird, that it is not really that important for (generalized) metric spaces.

Comment: @StefanPerko I'm not saying Cauchy completeness is not important for metric spaces. But I'm saying that an important aspect (for analysis anyway) is how it behaves with respect to continuous maps, not just $1$-Lipshitz maps. From that point of view, I don't want to drop continuous maps as being the wrong notion, I want to incorporate them while being able to distinguish the $1$-Lipshitz maps as special, and one way to do that (that I've high hopes for) is by keeping track of the moduli of continuity.

Answer (score 2):

A **modulus of continuity** is a function $[0,\infty]\xrightarrow{\omega}[0,\infty]$ so that

1. $r_1\leq r_2$ implies $\omega(r_1)\leq\omega(r_2)$.
2. $\omega(0)=0$ and $\omega$ is continuous at $0$.

Fix an order-preserving function $[0,\infty]\times[0,\infty]\xrightarrow{\oplus}[0,\infty]$.
A **$\oplus$-metric** on a space $A$ is a function $A\times A\xrightarrow{d_A}[0,\infty]$ so that

1. $d(a,a)=0$
2. $d(a,c)\leq d(a,b)\oplus d(a,c)$

Notice that the case where $[0,\infty]\times[0,\infty]\xrightarrow{\oplus}[0,\infty]$ is identically $\infty$ is exactly the case of a "premetric space''.

If $A$ and $B$ are $\oplus$-metric spaces, then a function $A\xrightarrow{f}B$ has **modulus of continuity $[0,\infty]\xrightarrow{\omega_a}[0,\infty]$ at $a\in A$** if

- $d_B(f(a),f(a')\leq\omega_a(d_A(a,a'))$

A **morphism** between such $\oplus$-metric spaces is then a function $A\xrightarrow{f}B$ equipped with a modulus of continuity $[0,\infty]\xrightarrow{\omega_{f,a}}[0,\infty]$ at every point $a\in A$.

Note that with this definition

1. uniformly continuous functions (which you defined) are morphisms that have the same modulus of continuity at every point.
2. non-expansive maps (i.e. $d_B(f(a),f(a'))<d_A(a,a)$) are morphisms with modulus of continuity the identity function.
3. continuous maps are morphisms that have forgotten what their moduli of continuity are.

As far as I know, category theorists have studied extensively the category of metric spaces and non-expansive maps between them because there $0$ is a two-sided identity for $\oplus=+$, and metric spaces end up being enriched categories with non-expansive functions corresponding to enriched functors.

Comment: So just to be clear, this is one possibility for a category whose objects are semimetric spaces. Right? There's no metamathematical precept that forces us to consider these morphisms and these morphisms alone. (To be fair the question was phrased in a way that suggests there would be.)

Comment: Yes, this is one possibility, but also it's the "best" possibility that I know of since 1) all the morphisms you would ever want from analysis fit naturally in it, and 2) it can be generalized to arbitrary enriched categories, though I'm not aware of anyone that has studied that generalization or how much of classical analysis can be ported over.